# Apache Spark vs. MapReduce

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, mapreduce

I've been looking up the differences between Spark and MapReduce and all I've really found is that Spark runs in memory and on disk which makes it significantly faster.

I also read that MapReduce is better for really huge data sets, is that just because you can have much more data loaded onto disk than in memory?

But presumably, with Spark, you're moving data between memory and disk anyway so if you're running out of space in memory, you move some back to disk and then bring in new data to process.

Basically, is there any real reason to use MapReduce anymore?

Comment: You should also look at Tez, which can be used in place of MapReduce, and in certain benchmarks is better than Spark.... In the end, the answer is it depends on your use case... Are you doing machine learning, or SQL, Graph queries, or Streaming? Then use Spark. Are you just manipulating some datasets or performing an operation you just cannot use Spark for? Or are you maintaining old code? Then MapReduce

Comment: @cricket_007 so it sounds like spark is overall better, though, than MapReduce. But when I looked into this, I saw people saying MapReduce is better for really enormous data sets and I don't really see how that could be when Spark can also use the disk but also uses the RAM. This is just a learning exercise, I'm not implemented either one.

Comment: The thing is that MapReduce + Tez will release resources as the intermediate tasks. Spark will hold the whole execution DAG in memory even if you aren't using parts of the previous results.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge here is simple and rare resolutions for Spark and Hadoop Map Reduce:

1. Hadoop Map Reduce is Batch Processing.
2. In HDFS high latency. Here is a full explanation about Hadoop MapReduce and Spark:

http://commandstech.com/basic-difference-between-spark-and-map-reduce-with-examples/

Spark:

1. Coming to Spark is Streaming processing.
2. Low latency because of RDDs.

Spark and Hadoop Map Reduce used for Huge data processing with less code.